Were cargo containers on the OV-1 Mohawk ever used, and if so where?
According to some specifications (e.g. the OV-1B Standard Aircraft Characteristics), the OV-1 Mohawk could carry cargo containers for the emergency resupply of ground forces. I failed to find more information about these containers or any pictures.
Where the supply containers ever actually developed, issued, and used operationally? If so, what models and where? Were there different containers for airdrop and airlanding?
(I realize these are several questions, but I believe they belong together. The perfect answer would be a link to photos, container designations, and a description, along with units and dates. But any one part might help with further search.)

There is evidence to suggest that cargo pods were developed to be dropped from wing-mount hardpoints for the purpose of emergency resupply. Whether they were ever issued or used operationally is not (to my eyes) possible to establish.
At issue however: Cargo pods, and especially wing-mounted pods must be designed to minimize the aerodynamic impact on the aircraft's performance.  As a consequence, their visual appearance is rarely distinct.  Consider the example, below, mounted to a F-16:

While at this point I'm speculating (I'll update with official docs if I find them), the likely candidates for cargo pod development would have been the Mark 79 Napalm cannister or a fuel drop tank. Photographs of the OV-1 may, therefore, depict such equipment but you'd never know it because it looks like a fuel tank or napalm bomb.
Some documents refer to the "M4A Supply Container."  M4A is a common file format, and M4 refers to so many pieces of materiel at this point that I've yet to successfully cut through the noise to find documents on that piece of equipment itself.
TL;DR - Likely developed, possible to have been issued and even carried, but good luck proving as much.

100% more information than I had so far. :-) But M4A sounds weird. M5 would be Mark 4 and A is an approved modification, but that should have another number following the A. Or is it /A?

@o.m. The references, probably all pulling from the same source, just say "M4A supply container." Verbatim. Three hours of searching and I haven't found any such equipment to link. I'll update the answer if/when I do but I'm not hopeful.

Actually, when I think about it... it seems plausible they modified an M4 20mm gun pod as a cargo box? The OV-10 carried that one, and that's the OV-1's successor.  I'll dig into the gun pod's history when I get a chance.
